# After postman account login, local data is gone from UI

Tags: postman

With recent updates in postman app, you need to have an account, else you won’t be able to view your collections/environment.

After I got my postman upgraded to latest version, once I logged in, all my postman local data is gone, not able to view them on postman UI

Comment: Found a workaround, you can locate all postman backup data inside %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Postman folder(windows), data should be saved in json file,  like backup-{backedup_date_time}.json

Comment: Your data can be exported from the UI in the section that I mentioned in my answer. You don't need to go to that file path location.

Comment: I don't see any option to export without signing to postman with latest version

Comment: Please read the steps from my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can `migrate` your data from Scratchpad into a Workspace from the `⚙️ > Settings > Data` option, after signing in.

You can also Export your data from the same menu option. This can be done on both the signed in and signed out version.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Scratch Pad is no longer available in Postman v10.18 and later.
Refer- https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/basics/using-scratch-pad/#entering-the-scratch-pad

Comment: You can either use the Lightweight API Client but still have the ability to Export your data or you can sign in, go to the Migrate option and add that data to a new Workspace to continue using Collections, Environments, etc.

Comment: lightweight client no longer supports exporting

Comment: You export the data via `⚙️ > Settings > Data` literally the way I wrote in the answer 